# Using SASS/SCSS syntax inside <style> tag

Tags: html, css, sass

Is it possible/allowed to use SASS/SCSS syntax inside .html file in  tag? I'd like to define  a variable inside .html file and than use it inside .sass file.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Simply put, **No**, SASS is a CSS preprocessor- if you're looking at implementing variables into your CSS, one way may be to simply apply the variable directly to a class in your document `head`- as long as it is included in your page after your SCSS output, it will overwrite any other setting for that CSS style.

Answer (score 4):

**Not inside normal HTML ..**

I use it inside Vue template, with installed sass as following:

```
<style lang="scss">
    /* SCSS here ._. */
</style>
```

Comment: inside a framework, with build-tools and scripts set up to transpile everything.