# Can you use Sass and compass when you write your css styles in your HTML file? What should you watch?

Tags: html, css, compass-sass

I just started looking into sass and compass because I see a lot of code on codepen that uses it. I noticed in the documentation that you had to have something like a sass folder and it watches for changes in that folder and when a save event occurs it updates the stylesheet folder with the regular css. I'm used to writing my css, especially when I go through short tutorials or for practice in the `style` tag in the html file. Is it possible to write my sass in the HTML file? Do I have to now write my css in a different file? if not how would I do it?

Comment: I suggest you have a read through the Sass language website http://sass-lang.com But certainly you will not be able to write your Sass in an HTML file as it needs to be processed into a CSS file

Answer (score 0):

**No, you cannot** to my knowledge. See [Using SASS/SCSS syntax inside <style> tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23079791/using-sass-scss-syntax-inside-style-tag).

The real question, though, is why would you want to use SASS at all? Some say it promotes and encourages poor CSS programming practice. The "features" it offers are in general of marginal usefulness. It adds another step to your workflow, and before you know it you will be fighting with gruntfiles and SASS versions and having Ruby installed properly. Personally I would also strongly advise against deciding to start using some CSS framework if it brings along the SASS/SCSS/LESS baggage.

Some preprocessors that we use in JS/HTML/CSS do have versions which can run in the browser, for development purposes. For example, you can run babel in the browser to convert ES6 to ES5. That is possibly because babel is written in JS, and it's not that hard to create a version which runs in the browser and does the transpiling on the fly. Or, to take one other example, you can arrange for Ember to compile templates from within the HTML. SASS, on the other hand, is not written in JS and there is no reasonable way to call it from the browser.

Comment: Thanks for answering and sharing your opinion. I'm interested in SASS because I see it all over the place  like in this pen: http://codepen.io/natewiley/pen/HiFwj . The amount of typing seemes to be reduced significantly at first glance. Plus I see it in job requirements. So i guess if I want to use it I should separate my CSS .

Comment: Right, i you need to learn SASS then you need to learn it, and in that case, yes, you need to externalize and preprocess it. Just remember, SASS is to CSS as jQuery is to HTML/DOM, albeit somewhat further from its end-of-life.

Comment: Agree with the "no" answer here, but I want to chime in and say that preprocessor languages aren't inherently bad. You don't *require* a Gruntfile, only the Ruby gem. You can manually compile every time you change CSS. There are also numerous watcher apps out there now that will do it for you, using their bundled versions or Ruby.